# How to create notification on frontend using heartbeat api for multiple custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, hooks, heartbeat-api

How can I get correct action hook on publish_posts for multiple custom types ?

I have a following problem, I can use this hook for posts or single custom post_type, but I don't know correct hook for multiple custom post types:

```
// Post publication for posts
add_filter ( 'publish_post', 'notify_published_post' );
function notify_published_post( $post_id ) {
```

I would like to publish to all even future custom post_types, so I would like to get something like this:

```
// Post publication hook for all custom posts
add_filter ( 'publish_anypost', 'notify_published_post' );
function notify_published_post( $post_id ) {
```

Comment: Does `publish_post` not work for custom post types?

Comment: It works but for only one, I can make it work for `publish_portfolio` for example, but I would like to make it work for all custom post types I have. Or did you mean if it doesn't work for all of them in default? No, I have tried it and it didn't work for custom post types.

Comment: i think question will contain `add_action` in example code instead of `add_filter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can achieve this by:

1.determine the custom post types by using [`get_post_types()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_types) fx

> It returns a list of post names or objects on basis of parameter you
>   pass

```
<?php
$args = array(
  'public'   => true,
  '_builtin' => false
); //pass parameter to array according to get all custom post types( parameter pass for demo only.modify it to get desire result)
$post_types=get_post_types($args,'names');

?>
```

2.add action to custom post type when publish

```
<?php
foreach($post_types as $post_type){
  add_action( 'publish_'.$post_type, 'ravs_notify_published_post' );
}
function ravs_notify_published_post( $post_id ) {
 $post = get_post( $post_id );
 // Here's the magic
 Wp_Heartbeat_Notify::notify( array(
    'title'     =>      'New Post by ' . $post->post_author,
    'content'   =>      'There\'s a new post publish, why don\'t you <a href="' .get_permalink($post_id). '">give it</a> a look?',
    'type'      =>      'info'
  ));
}
?>
```

**Updated**

Create a plugin to show realtime notifications [WP-Realtime-Notify](https://github.com/ravinderk/WP-Realtime-Notify)

**Edit**

Paste this code in `functions.php`.It'll print array of name of custom post types.goto [get_post_types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_types) and see all parameters.pass correct parameters which gives you required output( change `$args` ).if you get correct array of name of custom post types for required `$args`,change it with my [$args](https://github.com/ravinderk/WP-Realtime-Notify/blob/master/wp-realtime-notify.php#LC12) in plugin.

```
<?php
add_action('the_content','ravs_customPostList');
function ravs_customPostList(){
$args = array(
  'public'   => true,
);
$post_types = get_post_types($args,'names'); //get names of post types
print_r($post_types);
}?>
```

Comment: Ravs thank you for answer where should I put the code above? I would like to make work this simple plugin below which uses new WP 3.6 heartbeat API [plugin link is here](https://github.com/micc83/wp-heartbeat-notify/blob/master/wp-heartbeat-notify/wp-heartbeat-notify.php)

Comment: create a plugin, paste this code in plugin file.Activate it.Make sure `wp-heartbeat-notify` activated.hope this will work

Comment: thanks for your effort!, really appreciate it, the plugin is already created here [all plugin files](https://github.com/micc83/wp-heartbeat-notify/tree/master/wp-heartbeat-notify) , but I can't make it work , I have tried to delete the action hook part in `wp-heartbeat-notify.php` and insert your code but it gives me the error :( ,

Comment: don't insert my code in `wp-heartbeat-notify` plugin, make a new plugin.Newly created plugin using `wp-heartbeat-notify` plugin functionality.

Comment: I have let the original plugin untouched and I have created the new plugin with your 2 codes as you told me and I can't activate it, I will try to play with it all the night and I will let you know, thanks again Ravs, I thought that it will be more simple issue than I see it now.
`Fatal error: Cannot redeclare notify_published_post() (previously declared in /home6/dancersr/public_html/4ella/wp-content/plugins/wp-heartbeat-notify/wp-heartbeat-notify.php:35) in /home6/dancersr/public_html/4ella/wp-content/plugins/wp-heartbeat-multiple-notify.php on line 33`

Comment: code updated already.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9872/discussion-between-ravs-and-daniel-foltynek)

Comment: Ravs your new plugin works for posts and as Micc's original plugin probably also for one custom post type, but I can't make it work for multiple custom post types yet, can't wait to mark your answer as correct when multiple custom types will be working, it would be nice to mention the label name of custom post type in notifications

Comment: answer updated, read updated part of answer.it'll work, you have to change `$args` in my plugin for getting all custom post typeses name.just play with get_post_types fx

Comment: i'm also suggest you to change the question title like 'How to create notification on frontend using heartbeat api for custom post type' and also add new tag like 'Heartbeat api'

Comment: I have changed the title as you said and about $args, do you mean to change it like this ? `$post_types = get_post_types('name1','name2','name3','name4','name5');` the plugin already worked for 1 custom post type , priority and the question was put only because I need to make it work for all custom post types and posts, the tag Heartbeat api I am not allowed to create because I don't have reputation enough

Comment: I am very happy Ravs, right now your code works for all custom post types, I have marked your answer as right

Answer (score 1):

As i wrote on the doc this plugin has been full tested on WordPress 3.6-beta3 both on localhost and online but i'm not sure how it would work on later RC.

As soon as 3.6 release is coming out i'll check it out. For testing purpose i would suggest to download beta 3 here: http://wordpress.org/wordpress-3.6-beta3.zip

Remember that to see realtime notification you have to open two browser cause events are obviously not shown to the user that triggered them.

Hope this can help :)

Comment: Your plugin works perfect on RC2, you don't need to check it out, it works well for one custom post type or wp posts, I will wait for solution to make it work with all custom post types.